# Slow file trawler -- python

Tags: python, os.path, fnmatch, nested-for-loop

I've written a short script searches a directory tree for the latest files that match `"Data*.txt"` but it is painfully slow. It's due to the fact I've had to nest the for loops (I suspect).

Example directory tree:

```
ROOT
   |-- <directoryNameFoo1>
   |     |-- from  # This stays the same in each subdir...
   |            |-- <directoryNameBar1>
   |                  |-- Data*.txt
   |
   |-- <directoryNameFoo2>
   |     |-- from  # This stays the same in each subdir...
   |            |-- <directoryNameBar2>
   |                  |-- Data*.txt
   |
   |-- <directoryNameFoo3>
   |     |-- from  # This stays the same in each subdir...
   |            |-- <directoryNameBar3>
   |                  |-- Data*.txt
```

My question is: Is there a better/faster way to search a directory structure in order to find the latest files matching `"Data*.txt"` in each subdir?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import fnmatch
__basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

last_ctime = None
vehicle_root = None
file_list = []

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(__basedir):
    vehdata = []
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'Data*.txt'):
        _file = os.path.join(root, filename)
        if vehicle_root == root:
            if os.path.getctime > last_ctime[1]:
                last_ctime = [_file, os.path.getctime(_file)]
            else:
                continue
        else:
            file_list.append(last_ctime)
            vehicle_root = root
            last_ctime = [_file, os.path.getctime(_file)]

        
print(file_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to search a specific pattern data without any loop.
Like,

```
import glob
glob.glob('yourdir/Data*.txt')
```

and use `glob.glob('yourdir/Data*.txt,recursive=True)` when you want to search in all sub directory in your defined directory.

Comment: I still have to loop over the list that glob outputs it pretty much takes the exact same time.